# Git already up to date unless I reset

Tags: git, pull

I have a cloned repo I use for the live site and I have it pull from a bare repo. For some reason every time I execute "git pull" I get the already up to date message. But it's not up to date and not updated. If I do a git reset --hard HEAD^ and then git pull again, the changes come in.

What's the problem here and how do I fix it so that git pull will pull and merge changes in without needing a hard reset?

Comment: Please provide more details, it sounds like you really are up to date. When you do `git reset --hard HEAD^ && git pull` does `HEAD` really change? What does `git rev-parse HEAD` show before and afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the case if are working on a [DETACHED HEAD (see this SO question for more)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes)

[image: gitk detached head]

That happens when you [checkout directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467433/git-checkout-sha-and-heroku) a SHA1 commit reference, for instance.