# EGIT branches local vs Remote tracking

Tags: git, egit

I am new to GIT. I use EGIT with eclipse.

I have a question about branches where I see two sections "Local" and "Remote Tracking". If I have to work on one of the branches, I think there are two ways I can accomplish it.

a) Check out origin/featureBranch under remote tracking and work on it.

b) Right click under local and create a local branch and point to ref/remote/featureBranch and start working on it?

Are there any difference between these two approaches? which one is preferred?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

b) would be best.
a) would create a [DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696950/git-already-up-to-date-unless-i-reset/2697816#2697816), which would allow you to work on an "anonymous" branch, but would not allow you to push your work.
(See also "[Git Tip of the Week: Detached Heads](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/08/git-tip-of-week-detached-heads.html)" and "[detached head explained](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/detached-head.html)" for more on detached head)

For EGit, see "[Git Lesson: Be mindful of a detached head](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/05/29/life-lesson-be-mindful-of-a-detached-head/)":

[image: example of an Egit detached head]