# Why isn't Git tracking changes in a subdirectory?

Tags: git, github

I've created git repository, added code and pushed it to GitHub.

Then locally, I've edited the file `Eila.Analyser/Program.cs`, that was added to GitHub in first commit, saved it and `git status` says there's no changes.

Ok, I think, must have messed something up, `git reset --hard HEAD`, and as I understand that should revert everything, but my file is not reverted.

So I think I'm doing something wrong. I edit file in root folder, `git status`- shows there are changes, works as suspected, so it works on files in root folder, but not in sub folders.

Am I missing something obvious here?

UPDATE: Evidence, that file I'm editing was really commited (`git log --stat`):

[image]

if it helps, tree picture:

[image]

UPDATE2: Ok, I thought I really messed something up, so I've deleted folder, where was my solution, cloned once again from gitHub, and my local code still differs from existing in gitHub and git status sees no changes, `git log origin/master..HEAD` gives nothing.

Comment: Silly question: Program.cs isn't in the .gitignore file is it?

Comment: no, it is not. Also tried to change another file - app.config, that is in subdirectory also - and it does not work also.

Comment: @Giedrius are you in a detached head? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213826/egit-branches-local-vs-remote-tracking/8218067#8218067, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1000009/6309)? What does `git branch` returns?

Comment: `git branch` returns `* master`

Comment: See if your files are actually in your old commits do you see them by doing `git log --stat`?

Comment: It looks like it is, added screenshot to question of `git log --stat`, also it is visible on github.

Comment: And if modify again a file in a sub-directory, what returns `git status`? Is the any `.git` in said subdirectory (like `Eila.Analyser`)?

Comment: If edit again, `git status` says nothing to commit, there is no .git in subdirectory.

Comment: @Giedrius: I understand it says "nothing to commit", but does it says "nothring to add" (or "no changes")? If you don't add to the index, you won't have anything to commit (basic, I know, but just to be extra sure). And what is your git version? You are using msysgit, I suppose?

Comment: it says nothing to commit (working directory clean). I'm using git bash version, that came with git extensions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So finally it worked. I've removed changed files in local folder - then suddenly `git status` started to see, that those files are missing. So I've restored them and `git status` started to see, that files are modified.

Comment: Same here. Removed README.md and did "git status", then my changed file was in the list again.

Comment: I renamed the folder and git recognized it for me.

Comment: @AskYours, its so stupid, but that is the only thing that worked. :(

Answer (score 51):

Sometimes I have the same problem, especially when I have subfolder which is another git repo itself. The solution is: renaming the folders. Try switching the folder name to something else. Commit that, then rename it back.
If the subfolder itself is another Git repo, and you want it to be totally detached from the mainstream, and follow your repo, you should remove the remote of that subfolder first.

Comment: This solution seems clunky, but it totally worked for me

Answer (score 21):

For me the solution was

**Renaming the untracked folder**

Answer (score 19):

Try running `git update-index --really-refresh`.

I did have similar problems on Windows and that solves it.

You should also check the `core.ignoreStat` option with `git config`.

Comment: didn't worked, git config --get core.ignoreStat returned nothing.

Comment: CAREFUL WITH THIS ONE. I ran it and it undid the changes I had made. However I was then able to make those changes again and they were tracked.

Comment: @JasonSteele: I don't think that behavior might be caused by `update-index`. Like the name and documentation says, it just updates the index and does not change your working directory.

Comment: I have the same problem where I'm unable to get the latest diff of my code so from this answer I have did `git update-index --really-refresh` which works well for me. Thanks @Koraktor

Answer (score 6):

My case was exactly what Timothy mentioned. I had a subfolder that was also a git repo. I removed the git from the subfolder but the 'parent git' stopped tracking it. Renaming the folder via windows explorer didn't fix the issue but renaming it through git did the job.
So, I did '$ git mv folder-name folder-name-temp'.. than renamed back to its original name :)

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that I had a filename in my .gitignore file which did not exist. Removing this invalid filename from .gitignore solved the problem. Also, I deleted all the .gitignore files from subdirectories and only kept the top-level .gitignore file.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried `git update-index --really-refresh` and renaming the folder, with no success. This worked though:

- Duplicate the folder
- Remove the original
- Rename the duplicated folder to the original name

Comment: This Kind of worked for me. The scenario is that I would make a change and when saved it would not show as if anything was changed, even though I had edited a file. 
On running the above command the response was;

$ git update-index --really-refresh
src/databases/Database/dbo/Functions/udfIsRedeemable.sql: needs update

and now changes are listed, 
But it still does not fix the tracking of changes, new changes are not picked up.?

Answer (score 1):

Did you save the file?
when it happened to me, I found out that I had just turned off the "Auto Save" in my editor (VSCode), everything got back to normal when I turned it on again...

Comment: This was, embarrassingly, what happened to me as well. It was really confusing troubleshooting this, as I haven't manually saved a file in years so it was the last thing I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

PROBELM (In my case)
Performing a `git checkout -b <branch_name>` had no effect and my folder and files in that branch were still not visible locally, though they are on our gitlab server.

SOLUTION
Copied the SHA hash of last commit in that branch, then locally:

`git checkout -b <branch_name> #SHA Hash`

Now I see the expected sub-directories and files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but realised my issue was the ignore at top level.
I ignored the .php files so anything that was of .php could not be changed