# git: subdirectory treated as a repo on its own

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a template project.
I have then tore it apart, to make it my own project.
Now, `git` believe that a subdirectory is a branch of the original template project and even when I run `git add . -A` it does treat it as it was a repository.

When I was getting in the sub, the powershell was indicating that I was getting in a new repo. I executed `rm -rf .git` in the subdirectory.

Now however, `git status` says that the branch is up to date but in the `master` what I have is just an empty directory, while in `origin` I have all my code.

I [tried this with no success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034999/git-novice-git-is-not-tracking-changes-in-a-sub-directory).

Comment: Maybe your directory is a submodule. Try
`git submodule` to see if your directory appears there. If not, please be more specific and explain why you think that git treats the subdirectory as a repo.

Comment: looks like submodule check http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No trick did the job.
I have just had to delete the repository and start from scratch.
Ugly, but got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Your subdirectory is a submodule, so you should use `git submodule` instructions, as below -

```
git clone <main app>
cd main_app
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the subdirectory (let's say `subDir`) parent from where it is treated as it own repo.
2. Now, You're in main git repo
3. Change the name of that subdirectory (let's say `subDir1`).
4. `git pull origin <your branch>` (it will pull changes from remote)
5. Now you'll see that `subDir` and its name changed directory `subDir1`.
6. Remove `subDir1`

Now, `subDir` and it's content will be part of your main repo.