# EGit branch configuration: connecting local and remote branches

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, egit

I use Windows 7, Eclipse, EGit and write code for Android in Java.
I have 4 git branches in my GitHub repository (`develop`, `staging`, `master`, `junk`).
I set up my local repository in EGit. After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213826/egit-branches-local-vs-remote-tracking) I have created 4 local branches with local names (e.g. `developLocal`, `stagingLocal` etc.).
I set up the configuration for the `developLocal` branch (`Git Repositories` tab in Eclipse, right-click on the branch under `Local`, choose `Configure Branch...`, then set `Upstream Branch` property to `...remotes/develop`).
In Eclipse I switched to that branch (`developLocal`). But when I modified some code and committed it (`Team`->`Commit`->`Commit and push`), it went not to `develop` branch, but to `staging` branch.
Why it is so? What settings did I set up incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

With git changes which aren't yet committed aren't tied to any branch. In order to commit you first have to add the corresponding branches to the index, when you then create a commit it will incorporate all staged (added to index) changes and the commit will end up in the branch which was checked out before you created the commit.