# git "already up-to-date" is confusing me / how to force changes to be shown

Tags: git

What does the `Already up-to-date` message actually mean? Quite often when I do `pull` I get this message although I'm positive something has changed, and in fact when I look at the source files something has changed.

Is there anyway to force git to *always* show me everything that changes in the working directory as a result of a merge/pull or whatever operation. I'm guessing this might relate to fast-forward operations: I want them to appear like a merge and show me the files which have been changed.

---

*Example*

```
DirA> git push Repo

DirB> git pull Repo
DirB> git add somefile.txt
DirB> git commit
DirB> git push Repo

DirA> git pull Repo
"Already up-to-date"
```

The message appears even though `somefile.txt` has indeed been updated in `DirA`. That is, `DirA` was not actually up-to-date and a change has actually been made.

Comment: `Already up-to-date` means that nothing has changed on the remote side, so the `pull` didn't do anything. If you tell specifically what exactly you are doing, somebody can explain why you are seeing what you are.

Answer (score 0):

If you have committed local changes, and yet have that message, that should mean that you are in a [detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes), which would explain why Git doesn't display any change.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467564/6309) in order to "reattach the HEAD", and then your `git pull` will work better.

Comment: No, I'm not having this problem.  That is, my `push` and `pull` are definitely updating the files, but nonetheless saying `already up-to-date`.